# Html to WordPress scripts not working after enqueue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

it's like a small headache now, I am trying to enqueue the javascript files in functions.php but they are not working after 100's of tries. Let me know what is the issue, why my javascript file isn't working.

```
<?php

function ct_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('style_bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri('assets/css/vendor/2-bootstrap.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('style_pack', get_theme_file_uri('//unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css')); 

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ct_styles');

function ct_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ct_bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/vendor/2-bootstrap.min.js' ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'simplebar', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/vendor/4-simplebar.min.js' ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ct_pack', get_theme_file_uri( '//unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js' ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ct_lazy', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/vendor/lazysizes.min.js' ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ct_main', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/scripts.min.js' ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
    
    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ct_scripts');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`get_template_directory_uri()` = parent theme
`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` = child theme

```
function add_theme_scripts() {

 wp_enqueue_style( 'style_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/vendor/2-bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all');
 //Add other required css

wp_enqueue_script( 'ct_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/vendor/2-bootstrap.min.js',array ( 'jquery' ), null, true);
 //Add other required js

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: The question doesn't include these stylesheets or js files? Answers should address the exact problem in the question and include the user's code where possible.

Comment: Okay, next time I will take care of it.@FluffyKitten

Comment: You can always [edit] this answer to fix it this time :)